# Django: How do I include username in url?

Tags: django, python-3.x

Django2.1

My application wants to include twitter username in url, but an error occurs.
I can get uesrname correctly, but I can not connect to url correctly.
What is the cause?

An error occurs when accessing detail.

```
ValueError at /Temporary username/detail
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Temporary username'
```

```
#views.py
class MyDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Mymodel

class MyCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Mymodel
    form_class = MyForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.user = self.request.user
        return super(MyCreateView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('detail', kwargs={"pk": self.request.user.username})
```

```
#urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('<slug:pk>/detail', MyDetailView.as_view(), name="detail"),
    path('create/', MyCreateView.as_view(), name="create"),
]
```

Thank you

Comment: can you please share the code of detail view?

Comment: updated. Nothing was written in detailView, but in the case of initial <int: pk> it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default DetailView uses [get_object()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_object) method to fetch the object from queryset. `get_object()` uses [pk_url_kwarg](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.pk_url_kwarg). Meaning it looks for primary key in url with url parameter `pk`. Here you are sending the username as `pk` but in you `Mymodel` class, primary key is integer `id`. That is why the error is occuring.

So there are two possible solutions, **one is** you can change the primary key to username in Mymodel:

```
class Mymodel(models.Model):  # Please use CamelCase when defining class name
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, primary_key=True)
```

**Another solution is to** override the the `get_object` method inside `MyDetailView` to get the object:

Its better to rename url parameter anything other than `pk`, because username is not your `pk`. You can do it like this:

```
# view
class MyDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Mymodel

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(Mymodel, username=self.kwargs['username'])
# url
path('<str:username>/detail', MyDetailView.as_view(), name="detail"),

# get_success_url in MyCreateView
def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse_lazy('detail', kwargs={"username": self.request.user.username})
```

Comment: Thank you. I was able to solve it with reference to your opinion.

Comment: worked for me but didn't need the "get_seccess_url" part